# Custom OTP in Windows Server

Tags: windows, winlogon

I need to add custom field on Windows server 2012R2 logon screen where the administrator needs to Enter OTP send to his/her phone which would be validated by my custom OTP record. Can anybody help me to sort this out? I have already googled a lot this but could not find anything.

Comment: You would need a custom  [Credential Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/winlogon-and-credential-providers) to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for showing me direction but here is it where i have stuck. I tried this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/V2-Credential-Provider-7549a730 and now it is showing error here `IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(__in REFIID riid, __deref_out void **ppv)
    {
        static const QITAB qit[] =
        {
            QITABENT(CClassFactory, IClassFactory),
            { 0 },
        };
        return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
    }`
in Dll.cpp file